# Aplicar salto de linea a string

Tags: javascript, string, moongose

Hola buenos días tengo una tienda online donde genero enlaces personalizados, el nombre del producto es un string y muchas veces necesito poner un texto con dos productos y un salto de línea:

**Producto A**

**Producto B**

Pero sin embargo cuando lo visualizo me aparece todo de corrido **"Producto A Producto B"**

Aquí dejo un ejemplo real donde aparece // que lo he puesto yo, debería ir un salto de linea que no respeta https://www.imprentaonline24.es/producto-personalizado/aa0cc79b-75c5-4ee2-80d8-f767f51d5f2f

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me respete el salto de linea? No es factible hacer dos string.
La variable que uso en este caso es producto

El código es este:

```
const personalizadoSchema = new Schema({

producto: {type: String},
total: {type: Number, default: 0},
iva: {type: Number, default: 0},
totaliva: {type: Number, default: 0},
fecha: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
enlace: {type: String, unique: true}});
```

Comment: se que sería usando  \n pero como lo hago automático cada vez que haga un salto de línea con el teclado?

Comment: ¿No será con `<br>`?...

Answer (score 2):

Si el texto dentro de la base de datos ya contiene el caracter de salto de línea `\n`. Puedes usar la propiedad CSS: `white-space: pre;` para que ese salto de línea sea tenido en cuenta en la visualización HTML.

Por ejemplo, si no le pones la propiedad se ve así:

```html
<p>
<script>var texto = "Primer parrafo.\n\nSegundo parrafo."; document.write(texto)</script>
</p>
```

Pero si se la pones se ve asi:

```css
p {
white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>
<script>var texto = "Primer parrafo.\n\nSegundo parrafo."; document.write(texto)</script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ten en cuenta que en Html los saltos de linea son `</br>` y no \n, puedes **reemplazar los saltos de linea \n por `</br>`** en la variable antes de ser mostrada y con eso ya tendrá saltos de linea.

```js
var texto="150 cuadrípticos en tamaño cerrado 10.5x21cm abierto 40x21 Impreso en cuatricromía 4/4t  estucado mate 300 grs. Plegado en  ventana //\n\n110  libros fresado en tamaño A5. Impreso en cuatricromía 4/4t  todo. 104 paginas Interior sobre estucado 115 grs. mate y las cubiertas sobre 250 grs estucado mate. Encuadernación Fresada con lomo";
var parrafo=document.getElementById("productoPersonalizado");
parrafo.innerHTML=texto.replaceAll("\n","</br>");
```

```html
<p class="p-5" id="productoPersonalizado" style="color: #878787;font-size: 18px;"></p>
```